# Adding Google Analytics to all HTML Files

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to hundreds of pages of HTML. Theres no CMS as of yet, just static HTML pages.

I noticed all pages had:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.easy.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
```

Can I just add my Google Analytics code in there?

```
    <script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Or does it have to be in a file with a specific name like `analytics.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding GA to the page requires the HIGHLY recommended code snippet:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
</script>
```

so that you'll always have the latest library. If you host the analytics.js library yourself, you may not get any updates pushed out to you. The snippet can also be hosted in a file that gets included on every page of your site as well.

Comment: I mean just host the ga script in alaytics.js file.

Comment: What ga script? Do you mean `ga.js`? That's the classic analytics library.

Comment: Sorry im not sure the exact terminology but its the one Google analytics code that they tell you to add on your site. Like the one i just added above.

Comment: So Universal Analytics uses the "analytics.js" library. Classic GA uses the "ga.js" library. Long story short, use UA.

Comment: ok cool thanks. So just to confirm can I add this in header:    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.easy.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/analytics.js'></script>
Then the UA in a file there.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. You mean in your "analytics.js" file, add the UA code snippet in there. Sure, that should be fine.

Comment: Yes exactly. Would I be able to add it to a file called jquery.js instead of analytics.js?

Comment: I don't really know. You'd have to see if there were any other files with name, and if there were any conflicts. Why would you name the file that in the first place? `jquery.js` leads me to think it's only a jquery library.

Comment: I just found a footprint that all the .html files have in the header and they all have that script. There is nothing in that jquery.js (as i rebuilt the site from archive.org) so i thought that might make things easier. Its for someone else so i dont have access to GA to see what works and doesnt.